# cannot import name 'GPT2ForQuestionAnswering' from 'transformers'

Tags: pip, torch, gpt-2

[image]

> 1 import pandas as pd
> 2 import torch
> ----> 3 from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2ForQuestionAnswering, AdamW
> 4 from transformers import default_data_collator
> 5 from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2ForQuestionAnswering, AdamW
from transformers import default_data_collator
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from transformers import datasets
from transformers import TriviaQAProcessor, set_seed
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
```

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

Is your package up to date? I had the same issue so upgraded the package, and the error went away

Try:

```
pip install transformers --upgrade
```